# string splitting based on char number

Tags: c#, .net, string, split

```
string data = "0000062456"
```

how to split this string on 5 pieces so that I have:

```
part[0] = "00";
part[1] = "00";
part[2] = "06";
part[3] = "24";
part[4] = "56";
```

Comment: Please don't put tags in the titles (C#). Also, C# has no facility to split strings - it's the .NET Framework has the `System.String` class. That's why I added .NET to your tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Substring(int32, int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx):

```
part[0] = myString.Substring(0,2);
part[1] = myString.Substring(2,2);
part[2] = myString.Substring(4,2);
part[3] = myString.Substring(6,2);
part[4] = myString.Substring(8,2);
```

This can of course be easily converted to a function, using the index you need the substring from:

```
string getFromIndex(int arrIndex, int length)
{
   return myString.Substring(arrIndex * 2, length);
}
```

If you really want to get fancy, you can create an extension method as well.

```
public static string getFromIndex(this string str, int arrIndex, int length)
{
   return str.Substring(arrIndex * 2, length);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In case you are interested in a LINQ solution:

```
IEnumerable<string> result = Enumerable
    .Range(0, s.Length / 2)
    .Select(i => s.Substring(i * 2, 2));
```

Where you can replace `2` by any number you would like.

Comment: Be aware that this will work only with strings that are exactly divisible by the length of substring provided (2 characters in the example). In my case I needed to also capture the last substring that was shorter than the others. The change is easy but without it you will have one fewer strings than you might have wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Wrong language

```
string str = "0000062456";
List<string> parts = new List<string>();
for (Int32 i = 0; i <= (str.Length / 2 - 1); i++) 
{
    parts.Add(str.Substring(i * 2, 2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably a bit of an overkill for a string, since `Substring` is handy enough, but the general question is how to split a collection into subgroups of a given size. The library [`MoreLinq`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) has such a function: [`Batch`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/Batch.cs).
It can also take a lambda expression as the second parameter to convert the subgroups directly, so a solution can be:

```
IEnumerable<string> parts = str.Batch(2, String.Concat);
```

The above works for .Net 4.0. On 3.5 Concat need an array, so we can use `ToArray` or:

```
IEnumerable<string> parts = str.Batch(2, chars => new String(chars.ToArray()));
```

A nice side effect of this approach is that it protects you from edge case - it will work as expected even the length of your string doesn't divide evenly in the length on the sub-strings.